Why adversary have to do hash queries in RO model?
In MPC，it is common to use hash to extract the real input of malicious adversary under RO model. But I wonder why the adversary have to do hash queries rather than just select random values as the hash value to break the protocol?

I believe it's because, to actually use the RO output as a part of the attack, it is required to know the preimage.  If the attack doesn't need to know the preimage, the attacker need not be limited to random values, he can pick the values that makes the attack work the best.

As @poncho says, it’s a common trick in cryptography to ask someone to commit to something and then open the commitment. This forces everyone to choose their values independently, which stops many attacks. In ROM, a hashing gives a nice commitment where the security proof can peek at committed values, which makes the security proof easier.
